# Accessing the `links` property from a ember data query

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

When using the `JSONAPIAdaper`, and I query the store for models, the server response include the `"links"` property specified by [`json-api` spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-links), with a response like so.

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:4200/api/v0/blog-posts?size=10",
    "first": "http://localhost:4200/api/v0/blog-posts?size=10&page=0",
    "last": "http://localhost:4200/api/v0/blog-posts?size=10&page=1",
    "next": "http://localhost:4200/api/v0/blog-posts?size=10&page=1"
  },
  "data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "blog.posts",
    "attributes": {
      "published": "2015-04-04T00:56:36.768Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "revisions": {
        "data": [
          { "id": 1, "type": "blog.post.revisions" },
          { "id": 2, "type": "blog.post.revisions" },
          { "id": 3, "type": "blog.post.revisions" },
          { "id": 4, "type": "blog.post.revisions" }
        ]
      },
      "current": {
        "data": { "id": 4, "type": "blog.post.revisions" }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

> **Note:** I removed most of the elements in the data property and removed the included property as they make the example unnecessarily large. **Also** don't worry about the type names, admittedly they look pretty weird but that's how I setup my serialiser (to reflect the pod structure).

The route that requests it looks like this

```
import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model () {
    const store = this.get('store');
    return store.query('blog.post', { size: 10 });
  }
});
```

What I'm do is make a pagination mechanism for my blog by replacing the model with the data from the links specified in the links property.

How do I access this `"links"` property?

---

### Versions

- `ember @ 2.2`
- `ember-data @ 2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

I ended up extending the serialiser and inserting the `links` object in the `meta` object after record array normalization.

```
// pods:    app/application/serialiser.js
// vanilla: app/serialisers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  /**
   * will attach links to the meta object
   */
  normalizeArrayResponse (...args) {
    const normalized = this._super(...args);
    //
    // since the meta object is optional, it's
    // best to verify if it's null/undefined
    //
    if (normalized.meta == null) {
      normalized.meta = {};
    }
    normalized.meta.links = normalized.links;
    return normalized;
  }
});
```

So in my route I can access the links the object like so

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model (params) {
    const store = this.get('store');
    return store.query('blog.post', params).then(posts => {
      //
      // access the links object like so.
      //
      const links = posts.get('meta.links');
      return Ember.Object.create({ links, posts })
    });
  }
});
```

### Caveats

This isn't the best solution as it could possibly override any property called `links` in the `meta` object.

One way to overcome this is to use a symbol as the fields name, as symbols are unique so you can be certain you won't override any exiting names in the objects namespace. But I haven't tried this and it probably won't work all that well on older browsers and I'm not sure how ember's get method interacts with symbols.